# Ionic list about 100-150 elements very brake

Tags: list, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a list in an ionic-app with elements that contains a 20x20 px image on each. 
The problem is that when number of elements reaches more than 50 it begins to insanely lag.

Here is my code for the list:

```
<ion-content has-bouncing="true">
  <div class="item-wrapper" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div class="item item-avatar item-custom-avatar"
         ng-click="openProfile(user.ID)"
         on-tap="openProfile(user.ID)">
      <h2>{{ user.LAST_NAME + ' ' + user.NAME }}</h2>
      <p class="employees-work-position">{{ user.WORK_POSITION }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

How could I fix it? Lagging occurs even when I use a single pre-saved image for the every cell.

Comment: Have you tried the [collection-repeat directive](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/)? It target larger lists and render items on demand.

Comment: Just remember that on collection-repeat the repeated elements should be equal size in height.